# Install composer package by ignoring one of its dependencies

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I have a Symfony2 project and want to add the [AdminGenerator](https://packagist.org/packages/cedriclombardot/admingenerator-generator-bundle#v1.1.3) to it.

So I

```
composer require cedriclombardot/admingenerator-generator-bundle
```

And get the following error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - cedriclombardot/admingenerator-generator-bundle v1.1.3 requires twig/extensions 1.0.* -> no matching package found.
    - cedriclombardot/admingenerator-generator-bundle v1.1.2 requires twig/extensions 1.0.* -> no matching package found.
    - cedriclombardot/admingenerator-generator-bundle v1.1.1 requires twig/extensions 1.0.* -> no matching package found.
    - cedriclombardot/admingenerator-generator-bundle v1.1.0 requires twig/extensions 1.0.* -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for cedriclombardot/admingenerator-generator-bundle ^1.1 -> satisfiable by cedriclombardot/admingenerator-generator-bundle[v1.1.0, v1.1.1, v1.1.2, v1.1.3].
```

This is obvious, I have twig/extensions 1.3 and the package wants me to have `1.0.*`. If I downgrade twig/extensions to `1.0.*` it works perfectly, but I don't want to do that because it has a lot of deprecated things, and they will be removed soon in the 2.0 version of it.

How can I install the admin generator package while keeping my `twig/extensions` package at version `1.3` ?

My composer.json require, if it helps:

```
 "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "cunningsoft/chat-bundle": "^0.4.0",
    "knplabs/knp-time-bundle": "^1.3",
    "helthe/turbolinks-bundle": "~1.1",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.4",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~2",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.3"
  },
```

I want to do this not only to have the latest version, but also because later on I will do `composer update`, so I don't want to have problems, then, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddling with dependencies on a vendor package is not recommended and even if you did find a way to change it (in the `composer.json` file of the vendor package, for instance), you would lose all the benefits of using **composer** since the next update would gladly override / break your changes and your whole project.

But what seems possible is you could use the latest branch of the package, that doesn't require Twig Extensions at all :

https://packagist.org/packages/cedriclombardot/admingenerator-generator-bundle#dev-master

```
composer require cedriclombardot/admingenerator-generator-bundle:dev-master
```

Comment: Wow, it worked. But it still says there on the website that it requires it twig/extensions: ~1.0. How come it works even though that is there?

Comment: you can see that in the dependencies on packagist, it's not listed. So the website you mention might not be up to date. Always better to refer to the github repo (https://github.com/symfony2admingenerator/AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle) or the packagist page